# Calculating the tail bounds for a beta-binomial regression

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, beta-binomial-distribution

I have a beta-binomial regression model that depends on a probability $p$ and a given over-dispersion $\beta$ and is used to parametrise the distribution of $Y$ in the following way

$$ Y(x) \sim BetaBinom(n,\alpha,\beta) $$

with

$$ \alpha = \frac{p\beta}{1-p} $$

and

$$ p(x) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-xm}} $$

Given a value for $\beta$, $m$ and $x$, how can I now calculate the tail probability for a datapoint $v$? Can I use this as a goodness-of-fit measure for the single datapoint $v$? I understand that for a binomial distribution one should calculate these differently depending on whether $v$ is bigger than the expected value of the distribution, but how does this look like when the distribution is beta-binomial rather than binomial?